# jquery changing stored element value

Tags: jquery

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function () {

var dropDown = '<div class="hello">text1</div>  <div class="world">text2</div>';
$(dropDown).filter('.hello').html('hi');
console.log(dropDown);

})</script>
```

Simplified example. But what I'm trying to get is for the variable 'dropdown' to change the text in class "hello" from 'text1' to 'hi'.

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use find (or other operations) on a jQuery object (converted from string). It has to be added to a DOM element and then only operations can be performed on it.

```
var $result = $('<div />').append($(dropDown));
$result.find('.hello').html('hi');
```

Also you might want to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of `.filter()`

```js
var dropDown = '<div class="hello">text1</div>  <div class="world">text2</div>';
var $result = $('<div />').append($(dropDown));
$result.find('.hello').html('hi');
alert($result.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This seems to be doing what I'm looking for, but I'm not quite following the:
` var $result = $('<div />').append($(dropDown));`
It's appending the dropdown to... nothing?

Comment: by appending to an element like above, a DOM structure (tree) is created over which jquery's methods can be used. Essentially, jQuery needs a tree to traverse which can be done by doing as above

Comment: it is not appending to nothing. `$('<div />')` creates a new div element which will act as a root node. To this root node new elements are being appended ($dropDown). Now that there is a tree structure, jQuery will be able to traverse the tree structure and perform all the operations

Answer (score 0):

```
var idx = dropDown.indexOf('text1');

if(idx > -1){
    var correctedDropDown = dropDown.replace('text1', 'hi');
    console.log( correctedDropDown );
}
```

Try this way.